# Node.js Tedious Rows is an empty array but RowCount is correct

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, tedious

So this is my basic chunk of code that I'm running. I've got RowCount coming back as expected (there's only 5 items right now) and but rows comes back as an empty array.

Am I doing something wrong? By the way I'm connecting to SQL azure. I don't have any connection problems and I do believe that I've put the correct options (rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion to true).

Any ideas?

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

exports.list = function(req, res){
    var connection = new Connection({
    "userName": "myCoolUsername",
    "password": "SoMePa$$word",
    "server": "something.database.windows.net",
    "options": {
        "database": "mySampleDbName",
        "encrypt": true,
        "rowCollectionOnDone": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
    }
});

connection.on('connect', function(err){
    //if no error, then we are good to go.
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else
    {
        var request = new Request("SELECT * FROM Products", function(err, rowCount, rows){
            console.log(rowCount);
            res.send(rows);
        })
        connection.execSql(request);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved using `rowCollectionOnDone: true` option and `doneInProc` event on Request object like below. I don't know why callback function return empty array, when it should.

```
var config = {
    userName: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    options: {
        port: 2005,
        database: 'db1',
        rowCollectionOnDone: true
    }
}

connection.execSql(new Request('SELECT * FROM Products', function(err, rowCount, rows){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
    })
    .on('doneInProc',function(rowCount, more, rows){
        console.log(rows); // not empty
    })
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the code:

```
  var request = new Request("SELECT * FROM Products", function(err, rowCount, rows) {
      console.log(rowCount);
      res.send(rows);
  })
```

The problem occurs because rows is undefined. This callback only receives 2 parameters:

```
  var request = new Request("SELECT * FROM Products", function(err, rowCount) {
      console.log(rowCount);
      res.send(rows);
  })
```

Comment: Hi Philip. Thanks for your answer. Please don't write cryptic messages like: "rows = undefined => this callback get only 2 parameters". I had to read that several times to understand what you are talking about. Please present your answers clearly in a way that busy professionals can understand them quickly. [Answering Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I had to use this config to make it work

```
    var dbConn = await this.db.connect(); // Here add your connection code in connect() function
    const allRows = [];
    return await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       var SELECT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM your_table ';
       const request = new Request(SELECT_QUERY, function(err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) {

            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                const row = [];
                row.push({
                    metadata: column.metadata,
                    value: column.value,
                    toString: () => column.value
                });
                allRows.push(row);
            });
        });

        request.on('doneProc', function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
            console.log('onDoneProc');

            console.log('all rows',allRows);

            return resolve(allRows);
        });

        dbConn.execSql(request);

    });
```

Comment: Actually this works perfect

Answer (score 3):

as per the Tedious API

```
    callback
    function (err, rowCount, rows) { }
```

rows
Rows as a result of executing the SQL statement.

**Will only be available if Connection's config.options.rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion is true.**

I had to use this config to make it work

```
     var config = {
    server: "localhost",
    database: "*****",
    userName: "sa",
    password: "******",
    port: 1433,
    options:{rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion:true}
};
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer because it is the approach suggested by Tedious in their docs.

Answer (score 1):

set "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" is true

```
var config = {
    ...
    options : {
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion : true   // add this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but looking at the source, the rows get assigned an empty array when the `procDone` event is called. Perhaps, try setting `rowCollectionOnDone` to false? Also, there seems to be a `row` event emitted on the request. You could also subscribe to that and see if that gets you any output.